# Reuse ServletContainerInitializer in Jetty tests

Tags: java, testing, jetty, servlet-3.0

I have my servlets configuration in class `I` that extends `ServletContainerInitializer`. I register servlets and define mappings there. I don't want to do same work in my integration tests. Is there are common way to reuse `I` config in my jetty tests?

So I have `I`

```
public class I implements ServletContainerInitializer {
    public void onStartup(Set<Class<?>> c, ServletContext ctx) throws ServletException   {
        Servlet servlet = new MyServlet();
        ctx.addServlet("foo", servlet).addMapping("/*");
   }
}
```

And tests like

```
    Server server = new Server(0);
    Context servletContext = new Context(server, "/", Context.SESSIONS);


    Servlet servlet = new MyServlet();                           //Duplicated
    servletContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(servlet), "/*"); //Duplicated

    server.start();
```

How I can do it without duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a listener to jetty's life cycle

```
public class JettyStartingListener extends AbstractLifeCycleListener {

    private final ServletContext sc;

    public JettyStartingListener(ServletContext sc){
        this.sc = sc;
    }

    @Override
    public void lifeCycleStarting(LifeCycle event) {
        try {
            new I().onStartup(new HashSet<Class<?>>(), sc);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}

Server server = new Server(8080);
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.setContextPath("/");
server.setHandler(context);
context.addLifeCycleListener(new JettyStartingListener(context.getServletContext()));
server.start();
server.join();
```

tested on jetty-8.1.5.v20120716